# Rails 5: read-only enum attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a module used by several classes with an `enum` attribute `verification_status`:

```
included(self) do
  enum verification_status: { dont_verify: 0, pending: 1, in_review: 2, rejected: 3, approved: 4 }
end
```

I want this attribute to be read-only in a way that there'd be *no way* of modifying it except through one dedicated method, i.e. it should fail with an exception or return some error. The reason here being that I need it to be modified as a result of *another attribute modification*, so when someone calls `add_verification` (this is the dedicated method) on a verifiable object, a `Verification` with some properties is added to the list of previous verifications on that object, and its status is being set as `verification_status` for that object.

I'm aware of `attr_readonly`, but that doesn't really cover all of the cases I'm concerned about. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard Rails code **does not support read-only enums** so please consider the following as a kind of hack. Enum values in general can be set in two ways:

- by directly setting a value to the enum column name - this behavior can be suppressed using `attr_readonly`, as you stated, but I guess there would be no method left to actually *set* the enum value; that is why we'll rather redefine the setter method ourselves, and
- by calling `record.enum_value!` - the bang methods are dynamically defined and must be redefined to throw error instead of setting the value.

So, after declaring the `enum`, you need to redefine the setter methods, along the following lines:

```
enum verification_status: { dont_verify: 0, pending: 1, in_review: 2, rejected: 3, approved: 4 }

# redefine the enum setter  
define_method("verification_status=") do |args = nil|
  raise "use `add_verification` instead to modify this"
end

# redefine the bang enum setters
verification_statuses.each do |status, value|
  define_method("#{status}!") do
    raise "use `add_verification` instead to modify this"
  end
end
```

Then, to actually set the enum value, you need to use the private `write_attribute` method that sets the attribute directly, using the numberic enum value, e.g.:

```
write_attribute(:verification_status, self.class.verification_statuses[:pending])
#=> 1

# verify that the value has been indeed set
verification_status
#=> "pending"
```

Comment: I have one question about correctness of the `add_verification` method. Is there a more elegant/correct way to do this (calling `save` in the end looks strange for me):

`def add_verification(verification)`
  `write_attribute(:verification_status, Verification.statuses[verification.status])`
  `verifications << verification`
  `save`
`end`

If I understand correctly, `write_attribute` only modifies the attribute in memory, without saving it to the DB. That's why I call `save` (sorry for poor formatting, it's the best I could do).

Comment: Correct, `write_attribute` only sets the attribute in memory and you have to call `save`. Why does it look strange to you? There is perhaps a problem with the fact that `save` saves all changed attributes (if any), not just the verification status. You might also use `update_column` method if you like, to set the attribute directly in db, see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column) for more.

Comment: I can't check it right now, but I think `<<` here also saves changes made to the `verifications` array. So there's a duplication of DB updates if I use `save`, am I right? If I am, `update_column` is a better approach in this case. Díky!